# C++ deleting last symbol in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, fstream

I've encountered a problem. I have a code which should read the following text file, delete the last symbol and output the new text in other file. My problem would be: how to delete the last symbol? I've tried things like

```
 for(int j=0;j<10000;j++)
{
    if(simbols[j]=='\0')
    {
        cout<<j;
        minusOne = j-1;
        minusOne ='\0';
        break;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't really help and do anything I want. Any help would be appreciated!

P.S.
If it would be any help here's the full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
char simbols[10000]; int minusOne;
ofstream outFile("outFile.out");
ifstream inFile("inFile.in");

for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
{
    inFile >> simbols[i];
}

for(int j=0;j<10000;j++)
{
    if(simbols[j]=='\0')
    {
        cout<<j;
        minusOne = j-1;
        minusOne ='\0';
        break;
    }
}

if(outFile.is_open())
{
    for(int l=0;l<10000;l++)
    {
        outFile << simbols[l];
    }
}

inFile.close();
outFile.close();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Why just not save file content to string and then write to  a new stream `fileTextString.substr(0, fileTextString.size()-1);`??

Comment: Any code that uses lower-case ell as a variable name gets my downvote. What do you think you accomplish by choosing such a name?

Comment: Hmm... last time I've checked the variables was set by the guys who writes the code, not the 3rd party users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you meant to put

```
simbols[minusOne] = '\0';
```

instead of

```
minusOne = '\0';
```

Comment: Yep, that's the solution, damn I need to think more, the answer was kinda obvious :D but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

`minusOne` is just an integer variable, unrelated to the array of symbols. You wanted to make it a pointer to `char` and point to the last element of array:

`char simbols[10000]; char* minusOne = simpols;`

...

```
 cout<<j;
 minusOne += j-1;
 minusOne ='\0';
 break;
```

And, of course, the clean way of doing it is the way **bert-jan** has suggested.

P. S. Can't help but point out that the right spelling is "*symbol*", not "simbol".

Answer (score 2):

This is how to delete the last character of a string buffer:

```
char *buffer = strdup("hello world");

buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = '\0';
```